# How to include a single $ (dollar-sign) within the rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule for my .htaccess file. I want to include a single dollar sign within it. It is supposed to be something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^\$$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/something" [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that it doesn't work with a single dollar sign, so if I go to **domain.com/$** I get a 404. It works only with another letter, for example `^\$a$` - in such case **domain.com/$a** would redirect to **domain.com/something**.

The workaround is to create a new folder, rename it to **$** and put the .htaccess file there, but I would rather avoid creating multiple folders with no content for such purposes. I couldn't find any reference on the Internet (the [official Apache documentation for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) was not very helpful). I tried using multiple slashes in different combinations but everything failed. Am I missing something or is it just impossible to make it work this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it works exactly as expected in htaccess with RewriteRule ^\$$ and requesting "$".  Have you looked at the rewritelog / loglevel rewrite:trace8 yet?

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't test this rule anywhere else, but at least I know that I'm doing it correctly. Actually I have no idea what I've done - I was just looking for the logs you've mentioned and I've deleted some old system folders from my FTP that I considered unnecessary. And it started to work magically! Looks like I should have asked the server's support instead of posting my question here (apparently it was something wrong with my server). It's just my lack of experience in this field that convinced me that I was doing something wrong (because every other rule but this one worked perfectly).